# Using a FOR-EACH loop, how would you keep count of the number of scores over 85?

Tags: java

There is another test case not shown here with about 6 different test scores. How do I use a FOR-EACh loop to keep count of the number of scores over 85?

```
public class BetterLoop {
  /**
   * Accept an applicant if they have at least 4 grades above 85. Their non-CS
   * GPA counts as a grade in this case.
   * 
   * @param scores The applicant's list of scores
   * @return true if the applicant meets the requirements
   */
  public static boolean atLeastFourOver85(int[] scores) {
    /*
     * Use a FOR-EACH loop. How would you keep count of the number of scores over 85?
     */
    int total = 0;
    for(int score: scores){
      if (score < 85);
      total += 1;
    }

      

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JawadElFou I really can't remember. I deleted my first attempt hours ago and have been stuck on this ever since. Posting this question is a last attempt.

Comment: You should give some effort and show that you tried it. What do you think is a good way to keep count of something?

Comment: @alexquintanilla The Internet is full of tutorials on how to use a for-each loop in Java.  I'm sorry, but when your post includes no attempt and no reference to research, it's really hard to believe that this is your "last attempt".  There's a limited number of keywords in Java that could relate to this situation, and a limited number of ways to arrange them.  The least you could do is throw some keywords down and see what happens, no?  You're only looking at a couple (~5) lines of code here, so you're bound to get *something* right.

Comment: @Joker what I ended up trying to do was this: int total = 0;
    for(int score: scores){
      if (score < 85);
      total += 1;
    }

Comment: So you pretty much have the answer then.  The only mistake is that you've got the condition the wrong way around: you're counting the number of scores under 85.  You want to add 1 to `total` if `score` is *greater than* 85.  And then all you've got left is writing the return statement.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong what should I do with the "return false" in the original code? When I used the "return" example in the answer below, The "assertTrue" test case works, but the "assertFail" test case does not (or at least for the test cases given by my instructor.

Comment: You should replace it with the corrected version; i.e. the one that tests the `total` to see if you have ... counted at least 4 scores >= 85.

Comment: (If you are sure you have coded it correctly and you are still failing the instructor's unit tests, it might be related to this mysterious clause in the javadocs: *"Their non-CS GPA counts as a grade in this case."*  Have you any idea what that refers to?)

Comment: The updated code has the 'extraneous semicolon' problem that sometimes plagues new programmers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
public static boolean atLeastFourOver85(int[] scores) {
    /*
     * Use a FOR-EACH loop. How would you keep count of the number of scores over 85?
     */

    int found = 0;
    for(int score : scores) {
        if (score > 85)
            found++;
    }
    return found >= 4;
}
```

And here is the unit test:

class BetterLoopTest {

```
@Test
public void testLoop(){
    assertFalse(BetterLoop.atLeastFourOver85(new int[]{1,2,3}));
    assertFalse(BetterLoop.atLeastFourOver85(new int[]{1,2,3,86,86,86,34}));

    assertTrue(BetterLoop.atLeastFourOver85(new int[]{1,2,3,86,86,86,34,86,45}));
}
```

}

Comment: If you were the OP, and you were trying to learn Java, would you want somebody to just hand you the answer?  Why don't we try to guide the OP towards figuring the answer out on their own?  I understand that these types of questions are low-hanging fruit, but that doesn't mean answering them straightforward is the best thing to do.

Comment: You are probably right, we are giving people a shortcut instead of letting them learn. At the same time I do not see my job here is to judge people intensions and decide what is best for them. My job is answering the questions.